# profit drawdown of each column in data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, finance, performanceanalytics

I want to calculate the profit/drawdown of each column A:C in the data.frame below. Header A thru C can be considered like a stock ticker symbol. Each row can be considered the hourly closing price. The pricedate and hour could be combined to form a timestamp for this time series of data.

I have tried using the `fTrading` and `PerformanceAnalytics` package to calculate the max drawdown, but keep getting errors. I don't care when the  max drawdown occurs. I just need the amount of the max drawdown so I can use it to calculate the the profit/drawdown (profit divided by max drawdown) ratio.

Data:

```
hourlyclose <- data.frame(pricedate = as.Date('2019-12-18'), hour = c(1,2,3,4,5), A = c(3,5,6,2,4), B = c(1,9,7,11,4), C = c(0,2,5,4,9))
```

I am desiring an output of second data.frame with a column each for the stock symbol, the profit-drawdown ratio, and just the profit (which is the last row minus the first row in my example hourlyclose data.frame).

The resulting data.frame should look like:

```
Stock     pdd      profit
 A        0.25        1
 B        0.43        3
 C        9.0         9
```

I would prefer to use the tidyverse and either of those finance packages for operations as much as possible.

Drawdown definition: A drawdown is a measure of how much the price goes down before it reaches or exceeds the previously high price.

Max Drawdowns for each column:

For "A" the max drawdown is 4 because A was at a high of 6 and then went down to 2.

For "B" there are two drawdowns, but only one max drawdown. There is a reduction in stock price from 9 to 7, for a drawdown of 2. But the stock reaches a new high the next row to 11, but then reduces down to 4, for a drawdown of 7. So the max drawdown is 7 for "B".

For "C" the stock price has a reduction from 5 to 4 for a max drawdown of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the data in long format, `group_by` `name` and calculate the `drawdown` value using `cummax` and `max`. `Profit` is calculated by subtracting `last` by the `first` value and `pdd` is division of `profit` by `drawdown`.

```
library(dplyr)

hourlyclose %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = A:C) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(drawdown = max(cummax(value) - value), 
            profit  = last(value) - first(value), 
            pdd = profit/drawdown)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  name  drawdown profit   pdd
#  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A            4      1 0.25 
#2 B            7      3 0.429
#3 C            1      9 9
```

Comment: Does this calculate the drawdown correctly? Drawdown is not just the high minus the low. If B = c(9, 2, 15, 14, 13), the max drawdown would be 7. The order of the prices matters.

Comment: @otterdog2000 I am not calculating high - low for `drawdown`. `diff` calculates the difference of consecutive values. You can try with `B = c(9, 2, 15, 14, 13)` and then `-min(diff(B))` returns 7. Let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Ok, well the drawdown is not just for consecutive values. The drawdown is still 7 for B = c(9, 5, 2, 7, 8). Drawdown is a measure of how much the price goes down before it reaches or exceeds its previously high value, if it ever does.

Comment: I see. I then had misunderstood `drawdown` concept. I have updated the answer by using `cummax`. Can you check that now ?